# Excel formula with 3 conditions and three outcomes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let me start off by saying I am not an Excel expert.  I have been able to figure out most of the formulas thru research and trial and error but this one has me stumped.  I need a formula that does the following:

IF B48 and B53 are both > 0 return 4
IF B48 or B53 are 0 return 3
IF B48 and B53 are both 0 return 2

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You also need to code for negative values, even if they won't occur in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your data can be only positive or zero, you can use this formula using the exact logic you've described:

`=IF(AND(B48>0,B53>0),4, IF(OR(B48>0,B53>0),3,2))`

However this formula is much shorter and gives the same result:

`=2+SIGN(B48)+SIGN(B53)`